# How do I retrieve a unique set of parent nodes in my Nokogiri doc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css, xpath, nokogiri

I'm using RoR 5 with Nokogiri.  I use the following expression to obtain child elements from my doc ...

```
leaf_nodes = doc.xpath("//*[not(child::*)]")
```

I would like to retrieve the parent nodes of these child elements, so right now, I'm doing

```
    leaf_nodes.each_with_index do |leaf_node, index|
      node = leaf_node.parent
... process stuff
```

but this is slightly inefficient as I'm reprocessing some parent nodes multiple times.  Is there a way to retrieve a unique set of parent nodes prior to my looping through everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about:

```
leaf_nodes.map(&:parent).uniq.each_with_index do |node, index|
  # Here node is already unique parent node
  # process stuff
end
```

`leaf_nodes.map(&:parent).uniq` will extract the parents and will offer you the unique parent before your iteration. This way you don't have to call your *business logic* multiple times over the same parent element.